# How to use a JQ variable as an object key?

Tags: variables, syntax, key, jq

When I quote the key, JQ does not evaluate it:

```
$ echo value | jq -sR --arg key a '{"$key": .}'
{
  "$key": "value\n"
}
```

And when I do not quote it, JQ reports a syntax error:

```
$ echo value | jq -sR --arg key a '{$key: .}'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{$key: .}     
jq: 1 compile error
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a variable is used to specify a key name, it must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
{($key): .}
```

In fact, whenever a key-value pair is specified with a colon, the key must be enclosed in parentheses unless it is a JSON string constant.